# Cron job failing in script

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, cron

I have a script for an assignment at school and i am totally stuck on the cron statement. The script has to ask for a date and time (user input) to send a file (user input) and to an email address (user input) I have got everything working except when in passes to the cron job.

This is the error:

```
emailmarc.sh: line 80: syntax error near unexpected token `('
emailmarc.sh: line 80: `cat <(crontab -l) <(echo "$minutes $hour $day $month * $M_SCRIPT") | crontab -'
```

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_ERRORS='no'
M_SCRIPT='./mscript.sh'
echo
echo -n "Enter the date as MMDDHHMM >"
read date

if [ ${#date} -eq 8 ]
    then

        month=${date:0:2}
        day=${date:2:2}
        hour=${date:4:2}
        minutes=${date:6:2}

    else
        echo "Date is invalid"
        INPUT_ERRORS='yes'

fi


echo  "month: $month  day: $day Hour: $hour minutes: $minutes "



echo -n "Enter the full path and file name for your email attachment >"
read filename

if [ -f "$filename" ]
then
    echo "$filename found."
else
    echo "$filename not found."
    INPUT_ERRORS="yes"

fi


echo -n "Enter your email address >"
read email

if [[ $email == *"@"* ]]

    then

        echo " valid email address"

    else
        echo "$email is not a valid email address:  "
        INPUT_ERRORS="yes"

fi

if [ "$INPUT_ERRORS" == "no" ]

    then

        echo "all is okay.  setting up cron job"

        touch mscript.sh

        cat <(crontab -e) <(echo "$minutes $hour $day $month * $M_SCRIPT") | crontab -

fi
echo '#!/bin/bashl’  > $M_SCRIPT

echo 'mutt -s “Here’s your email from Cron and Marc” -a $filename $email'  >> $M_SCRIPT
```

I am very new to linux and shell script

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Marc

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Avoid relative paths (`./mscript.sh`), use paths (`mscript.sh`) or fill $PATH with useful paths.

Comment: Thank you for the link to shellcheck.net it enabled me to fix a few syntax errors and switches... That said shellcheck.net said the script was fine but I still have the same error in the     cat <(crontab -e) <(echo "$minutes $hour $day $month * $M_SCRIPT") | crontab -

Comment: I think you should try `crontab -l` not `crontab -e` on that line.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it still fails at that point with the same error even with -l